# Enforcing return values with Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have a class that has two methods for generating and decoding `jsonwebtokens`. This is what the class looks like.

```
interface IVerified {
  id: string
  email?: string
  data?: any
}

export default class TokenProvider implements ITokenProvider {
  public async generateToken({ id, email }: ITokenDetails): Promise<string> {
    return sign({ id, email }, CONFIG.JWT.secret, {
      subject: id,
      expiresIn: CONFIG.JWT.expires,
    })
  }
  

  public async decodeToken(token: string): Promise<IVerified> {
    const user = verify(token, CONFIG.JWT.secret)
    return user as IVerified
  }
}
```

In the `decodeToken` method, as you can see from above, it takes in a token and is meant to return the decoded values embedded in the token. But vscode Intellisense shows that `jwt.verify()` method returns a `string | object`. How can I override this to enforce the method to return some user attributes? Instead of getting `string | object`, I want to return the attributes described by the `IVerified` interface stated above. Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you implementing that `interface` somewhere? Try to convert it to `Type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally have two options:

1. Coerce the result to a `IVerified` like you do there (you might have to do `return (user as any) as IVerified;` though to get typescript to do what you want. This is fine as long as you can guarantee that the `object` returned from `jwt.verify` adheres to the `IVerified` interface.
2. Create a helper function that takes in a `string | object` and does the necessary logic to do runtime validation, deserialization, etc, in order to ensure you get an `IVerified` back:

```
private function validateDecodedToken(input: string | object): IVerified {
  // ... do whatever you need to parse/deserialize/validate/etc here
}

public async decodeToken(token: string): Promise<IVerified> {
  const user = verify(token, CONFIG.JWT.secret);
  return this.validateDecodedToken(user);
}
```

This is the more "robust" approach, but might be overkill if there
are other guarantees in the system.